# VSTS getting sometimes 400 Bad Request

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I'm developing an extension to VSTS that calls getTeamDaysOff RestAPI.
It usually works but sometimes, i'm getting "400 Bad Request" response with that Json: 
> {"name":"TFS.WebApi.Exception","status":400,"responseText":"{\"count\":1,\"value\":{\"Message\":\"The request is invalid.\"}}","serverError":{"count":1,"value":{"Message":"The request is invalid."}}}

My code is:

```
 var context = VSS.getWebContext();
 var workClient = TFS_Work.getClient();
 var teamContext = { projectId: context.project.id, teamId: context.team.id,     project: &quot;&quot;, team: &quot;&quot; };
 _iterationId = VSS.getConfiguration().iterationId;
 _witClient = VSS_Service.getCollectionClient(TFS_Wit_WebApi.WorkItemTrackingHttpClient);

 workClient.getTeamDaysOff(teamContext, _iterationId).then(process);
```

Any ideas? where could i find more help?

Comment: Can you show the entire code which you used to get team's days off? And based on the 400 state and the response, it's mainly caused the `_iterationId` is invalid.

Comment: Has your problem been solved for now?